# Is there a way to obtain information about the instrument to which a Logic Pro X Script is attached?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

Is it possible for a Logic Pro X midi script to query information about the instrument to which it is attached? For example, find out if it is transposed or has a particular midi range filter?  I have been all through the Apple documentation on the scripter and just don't see that this is possible. https://support.apple.com/en-md/guide/logicpro/lgce728c68f6/mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Can Scripter plug-in of Logic Pro X query information about the instrument of its channel strip?

> NO

Scripter is a built-in MIDI FX plug-in of Logic Pro X.

[MIDI FX](https://support.apple.com/en-md/guide/logicpro/lgcef1c11e8f/mac) are plug-ins inserted in software instrument channel strips that process or generate MIDI data —played from a MIDI region or a MIDI keyboard— in real time.

MIDI plug-ins are connected in series `before the audio path of a software instrument` channel strip and hence act as a modulator (using MIDI/CC/PC data) for various parameters of a software instrument.

[image: simplex]

As the signal flow is [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_communication) (one directional), Scripter cannot query information about instrument.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense technically.  It would be neat if the script could at least see the track name (and/or the MIDI name), which I imagine exists somewhere "above" the scripter intake? Then a single script could behave a little differently for different instruments.